# UIloader does not work well

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an UIloader in my .fla project.The source of my UIloader is a .swf that the .swf contain an UIloader inside too. the source of the second UIloader is another .swf .
when I want to publish my project it does not work. What should I do now?

Comment: You should try to explain your problem more clearly.. And attach relevant code.

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you aiming to do? How have you attempted to implement it? We can't without stuff like that.